# How to fix position while refreshing the web page inside a scrolling table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I just found this tutorial : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-table-with-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body/
It works perfectly for me but I need to refresh the web page and be in the same row as before in the table (for example a table with 10 000 rows, i need to stay at the 600th row after resfreshing the web page).
I just add :

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var scrollpos = localStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
        if (scrollpos) window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('scrollpos', window.scrollY);
    };
</script>
```

But it doesn't work because I stay on a web page fixed and i'm scrolling inside it. it's because my scrolling vertical bar is contained in the table and not in the web page.

How can I reload ly web page keeping the position of my vertical scroll bar ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    
<!---Without refresh Dispositif-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    var scrollpos = localStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
    if (scrollpos) window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);
});
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('scrollpos', window.scrollY);
};
    
</script>

<style>

.fixTableHead {
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 600px;
    }
    .fixTableHead thead th {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
    }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;        
      width: 100%;
    }
    th,
    td {
      padding: 8px 15px;
      border: 2px solid #529432;
    }
    th {
      background: #ABDD93;
    }
    
</style>

 
<div class="fixTableHead">

    <table class="table table-striped header-fixed" id="tableau">

        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>

            </tr> 
        </thead>


        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>15</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to replace `window.scrollY` with your table's [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) and also, instead of scrolling the `window` to the scroll position, you should set `scrollTop` on the table element.

In your markup, the scroll happens inside the `.fixTableHead` element, which is the `<table>`'s wrapper.

Therefore, the following should work:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const scrollpos = localStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
  if (scrollpos) {
    const scroller = document.querySelector('.fixTableHead');
    if (scroller) {
        scroller.scrollTop = scrollpos;
    }
  }
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  const scroller = document.querySelector('.fixTableHead');
  localStorage.setItem('scrollpos', scroller ? scroller.scrollTop : 0 );
};
```

See it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/5z2vL4u6/).
Scroll down and the press <kbd>Run</kbd> button again. You should see the app re-rendering at the same position.

Note: unfortunately, this can't be demo-ed in a SO snippet, as SO blocks access to `localStorage` from its snippets.

Since you seem to use jQuery, here's a jQuery version of the same script:

```
(function($){
  const selector = '.fixTableHead';
  if ($(selector).length) {
    const el = $(selector).eq(0)[0];
    el.scrollTop = localStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
      localStorage.setItem('scrollpos', el.scrollTop);
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Note: you should run the script after the scroller element has been added to the page, or it won't work.

Comment: Ok, I just add my code in order to be more specific.How can I replace windows.scrollY by my table offsetTop ? With the table's id ?

Comment: You're welcome, @Chev. I also wrote a jQuery version of it, since you seem to load jQuery anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const scrollpos = localStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
  if (scrollpos) {
    const scroller = document.querySelector('.fixTableHead');
    if (scroller) {
        scroller.scrollTop = scrollpos;
    }
  }
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  const scroller = document.querySelector('.fixTableHead');
  localStorage.setItem('scrollpos', scroller ? scroller.scrollTop : 0 );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why would you copy the code from my answer and post it as your own?